# Css Transformation Transition

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, transition, transformation

I have a simple situation, where I've created an SVG polygon with this code:

```
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <g>
    <polygon points="200,100 400,150 200,200"/>   
  </g>
</svg>
```

And I've applied two transformations to it with this:

```
g {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 150);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.move {
   fill: red;
   transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 400, 150)
}
```

I then apply and remove the `.move` class and I get a very ugly transition between these two states as you can see in this pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpaMvo

## Question

Can we animate from the bounding box of the original polygon to the bounding box of the final polygon. I know that I could just modify the way I am defining the coordinates of the polygon, but as you can imagine; I need them defined in this way.

Comment: Any reason why this was voted down?

Comment: Appears to be a by-browser thing. Chromium looks weird, while Firefox shows what I'd expect.

Comment: Oh wow, I just checked it on firefox and you're right! So this isn't a bug in chrome?

Comment: I'm not sure what (if anything) the spec says with regards to transforming martices.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this behaviour occurs with everything except chrome - ie: it looks like a chrome bug I believe.

Comment: I just quickly looked over the spec for transitions, and it doesn't specify a way to calculate intermediate positions, so it's technically an implementation detail. I imagine the Chromium team will pick this up eventually if you file a bug, however. I _might_ send an email to the CSSWG mailing list regarding this to see if they have any opinions.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate that! This has been causing me havoc all day :P

Comment: Interesting. Is the color supposed to transition as well? It does in Chrome, but not in Mozilla.

Comment: The color transitions fine for me in Mozilla.

Comment: yes the color should transition too

Comment: For anyone thats interested https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=797472